# How to read component link field using XSLT in tridion?

Tags: 2011, xslt

How to read component link field using XSLT in tridion?

In a component there is a field called "abc" which is a component link field. In that component link, I have a component with fields "a", "b", "c". I need to retrieve the value from that a, b, c text fields.

Comment: take a look at https://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/implementing-the-xslt-mediator-part-1/#xsltCT

Comment: what exactly do you mean with read? the field itself is an `xlink` element, so you can read its `href` attribute and find the TCMURI

Comment: In a component there is a field called "abc" which is a component link field, in that component link i have a component with fields "a", "b", "c" I need to retrieve the value from that a, b , c text  fields.

Comment: @saxena, questions asked in a comment you can best answer by editing your original question, and supplying the answer there. That is better readable, since you have formatting options there too. When done, you can delete the comment, so it doesn't get messy. Right now your question is not very clear. which is not strange since it is only a single sentance and doesn't really explain what you are trying to do, so it can definitely benefit from editing and supplying more detailed information.

Comment: Additionally I'd suggest you put any examples of what you've tried (it could be you've tried the correct thing but there's a syntactical issue - or it could be you've gone down the wrong path and someone can redirect you).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to read Component Link related text fields on XSLT Component Template.

You can perform as below,

```
<!-- Gets the Component Link Uri -->
<xsl:variable name="abcLink" select="/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/ref:XYZ/ref:ABCLink/@xlink:href" />
<!-- Gets the Content of Link Component  -->
<xsl:variable name="abcLinkField" select="document($abcLink)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/ref:ABC" />
<!-- Prints "A" field related content -->
<xsl:value-of select="$abcLinkField/ref:AField/text()" />
<!-- Prints "B" field related content -->
<xsl:value-of select="$abcLinkField/ref:BField/text()" />
<!-- Prints "C" field related content -->
<xsl:value-of select="$abcLinkField/ref:CField/text()" />
```

Here **`document($abcLink)`** invokes the protocol handler to get the linked item through the URI specified, and from there onwards you can simply proceed as with any item

Comment: could be useful to add that `document($abcLink)` invokes the protocol handler to get the linked item through the URI specified, and from there onwards you can simply proceed as with any item.

Comment: @BartKoopman: Thanks Bart. I have added the information.